# How to load variables values from teamcity to configmap

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, devops, configmap, teamcity-7.0

I want to pull variables from the TeamCity. the same way as we defining it in the deployment.YAML file. and need to put them into a config map resources for that application.
I have tried like  this

GS_HOST: "[[ .Env.gHost ]]"
like name :value.but after deployemt nothing will be returned.

[ConfigMap.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuhfR.png)

[deployment.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KteLW.png)

same is working fine when [[Env.gHost]] is edited in deployment.yaml as

Env:
 name:gHost
 value:[[Env.gHost]]
please find the images attached for the configMap that is not working

Comment: You need to provide more information. You want to use variables from TeamCity and apply them in ConfigMap? How did you do this? You need to specify what you want, what did you try and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have setup the variables in teamcity and am taking the variables into deployment.yaml by specifiying the [[Env.teamcityVariable]] .Currently am looking to change the environment variables specified in deployment.yaml into another config map. I will attach the sample config map and sample deployment.yaml that i i used.